# ARCore - Does Augmented Image detection work on the Front Camera?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, front-camera

I'm trying to modify the sample "augmentedimage" application within the sceneform SDK to enable image tracking on the front camera instead of the back camera.

I've added an override function for "getSessionFeatures" in the AugmentedImageFragment class which extends ArFragment to return a new feature set including Session.Feature.FRONT_CAMERA.  This does appropriately switch the view to the front camera but image tracking doesn't work.  I've also tried to recreate the image database with the sample images flipped horizontally in case it was a mirroring issue but that didn't fix the problem either.

```java
@Override
protected Set<Session.Feature> getSessionFeatures() {    
   return EnumSet.of(Session.Feature.FRONT_CAMERA);
}
```

No errors are thrown and the application does show the camera preview for the front camera but no augmented images are ever detected.